# Using Microsoft Solver Foundation in SQL Server CLR Assembly

Tags: c#, sql-server, clr, sqlclr, ms-solver-foundation

I currently am writing my own CLR Stored Procedure and I need to use a solver from Microsoft Solver Foundation.

In order to be able to add the reference to Microsft Solver Foundation in my CLR Project, I need to add that assembly to my SQL Server instance [(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859296/reference-class-library-in-sql-server-clr-project). So I [installed MS Solver Foundation Redistributable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff524499%28v=vs.93%29.aspx) and registered it in SQL Server using the following script as server admin:

```
USE MYDB

ALTER DATABASE MYDB SET TRUSTWORTHY ON WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

ALTER DATABASE MYDB SET TRUSTWORTHY ON

CREATE ASSEMBLY MicrosoftSolverFoundation
AUTHORIZATION dbo
FROM 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Microsoft.Solver.Foundation.dll' 
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Assembly 'MicrosoftSolverFoundation' could not be installed because existing policy would keep it from being used.
```

---

Additional Information

CLR Version:

```
directory   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\
version v4.0.30319
state   CLR is initialized
```

SQL Server Version:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3128.0 (X64) 
Dec 28 2012 20:23:12 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)
```

Answer (score 0):

This MSDN post seems to talk about the same thing, and recommends using the [mscorcfg.msc](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bc0cxhc.aspx) tool to look at the Runtime Security Policy.

It also mentions the [Fusion Log Viewer](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) to see if anything is being logged while you are trying to create the assembly.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6546340a-2cf7-4308-88d0-c403cebdb66b/create-assembly-error-could-not-be-installed